# Drupal mime mail send in bcc

Tags: email, drupal

I'm using the Mime mail module to send e-mail from my drupal site.
But now i would like to send a copy of a mail being send to an admin, i could of course send the mail twice but i would rather like to send it in 1 mail to all recipients at once.

So i was wondering if it's possible to send a mail in BCC using Mime Mail?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$message['headers']['Bcc'] = 'email@address.com';
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it not just this:

```
$headers = array(
  'Cc' => <Cc mail address>,
  'Bcc' => <Bcc mail address>,
);
```

Then pass this to the `mimemail()` function?